# More cowbell...!

Tags: code-golf, string

You are providing tech support to *the* Bruce Dickenson as he produces a Blue Öyster Cult recording session. When he asks for [more cowbell](https://vimeo.com/55624839), you can give it to him.

### Your task

Write a program or function that takes a string (or equivalent in your language) as input, and outputs a related string containing one more cowbell.

### How many cowbells does a string contain?

The number of cowbells a string contains equals the maximum number of distinct copies of "cowbell" that can be obtained by permuting the characters of the string. For example, `"bbbccceeellllllooowwwwwwwww"` contains 3 cowbells, while `"bbccceeellllllooowwwwwwwww"` and `"bbbccceeelllllooowwwwwwwww"` each contain 2 cowbells, and `"cowbel"` contains 0 cowbells.

### How should the output be related to the input?

The output should consist of the concatenation, in this order, of the input string and the shortest prefix of the input string needed to increase the number of cowbells.

For example, `"bbbccceeelllllooowwwwwwwww"` only needs one additional `"l"` to contain 3 cowbells instead of 2; the shortest prefix that contains that `"l"` is `"bbbccceeel"`. Therefore, if the input is `"bbbccceeelllllooowwwwwwwww"`, then the output should be `"bbbccceeelllllooowwwwwwwwwbbbccceeel"`.

### Technicalities

- You may assume that the input contains only printable ASCII characters. If there are one or two characters that are annoying for your language's string processing (such as newlines or `\`), you can assume that the input doesn't contain them—just mention this restriction.
- You may further assume that the alphabetic characters in the input are all lowercase, or all uppercase. If you choose not to assume one of these, count cowbells case-insensitively.
- You may further assume that the input contains at least one copy of each of the characters `b`, `c`, `e`, `l`, `o`, and `w`. This is equivalent to assuming that some prefix of the string can be concatenated to it to produce a string that contains more cowbell. (Note that the input string itself need not contain a cowbell.)
- If your language has a builtin that solves this problem ... then totally use it, seriously, how awesome is that.

### Gold-plated diapers

Since recording studio time is expensive, your code must be as short as possible. The entry with the fewest bytes is the winner!

### Test cases

([pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/q0874DEP) for easier copy/pasting)

Test input #1: `"christopher walken begs for more cowbell!"`

Test output #1: `"christopher walken begs for more cowbell!christopher wal"`

Test input #2: `"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`

Test output #2: `"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogthe quick brown fox jumps over the l"`

Test input #3: `"cowbell"`

Test output #3: `"cowbellcowbell"`

Test input #4: `"cowbell cowbell cowbell"`

Test output #4: `"cowbell cowbell cowbellcowbell"`

Test input #5: `"cowbell cowbell cowbel"`

Test output #5: `"cowbell cowbell cowbelcowbel"`

Test input #6: `"bcelow"`

Test output #6: `"bcelowbcel"`

Test input #7: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`

Test output #7: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl"`

Test input #8: `"cccowwwwbbeeeeelllll"`

Test output #8: `"cccowwwwbbeeeeelllllccco"`

Test input #9: `"be well, programming puzzles & code golf"`

Test output #9: `"be well, programming puzzles & code golfbe well, programming puzzles & c"`

Test input #10: `"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. wow!"`

Test output #10: `"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. wow!lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut lab"`

Test input #11:

```
"c-c-b-c

i have a cow, i have a bell.
uh! bell-cow!
i have a cow, i have a cowbell.
uh! cowbell-cow!

bell-cow, cowbell-cow.
uh! cow-cowbell-bell-cow.
cow-cowbell-bell-cow!
"
```

Test output #11:

```
"c-c-b-c

i have a cow, i have a bell.
uh! bell-cow!
i have a cow, i have a cowbell.
uh! cowbell-cow!

bell-cow, cowbell-cow.
uh! cow-cowbell-bell-cow.
cow-cowbell-bell-cow!
c-c-b-c

i have a cow, i have a bell"
```

Comment: Anyone who answers in [COW](http://web.archive.org/web/20130403133623/bigzaphod.org/cow/) earns ten internet points.

Comment: I think it would be much easier for people to handle the input/output cases if you formatted them in a single code block. As it stands it takes up a lot of space and isn't very copy paste friendly.

Comment: Pastebin link added for copy/pasting. If there's a way to hide/collapse/show the test cases in this post, thus saving vertical space, I'd love to learn it.

Comment: Well normally people use `test case -> result` in one large preformatted code block. It's much nicer aesthetically and easier to copy paste.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but who is Bruce Dickenson, and how is he related to BOC? Edit: made my way through my confusion, and found [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_cowbell)

Comment: Simple answer: count C,O,W,B,E,L,L and output its minimum

Comment: @MatthewRoh Apart from the fact that there are two `L`s in the word, this is not what the challenge asks.

Comment: @Pavel: I guess this is impossible in COW: I can see no way to either print a character that´s not directly from input or to reset the input pointer.

Comment: am I supposed to count `cowbel` letters, or should I also be including uppercase `COWBEL` letters as well? Something I missed in the question?

Comment: @GoldenRatio you missed `You may further assume that the alphabetic characters in the input are all lowercase, or all uppercase. If you choose not to assume one of these, count cowbells case-insensitively.`

Answer (score 13):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>50</s> <s>42</s> 38 bytes

```
T$<(MN{_NaM"lcowbe"}//^2M[aYa@<i])++iy
```

Pass the string in as a command-line argument, quoted if necessary. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@x@iYqPh61cd75foq5STnF@elKpUq68fZ@QbnRiZ6GCTGauprZ1Z@f//f7BcTo4ChAYA)

#### Explanation

I'm going to explain this in two parts: the cowbell function and the full program. First, here's the function that computes the amount of cowbell in a string:

```
MN{_NaM"lcowbe"}//^2
```

`{...}` defines a function. Many Pip operators, when applied to a function, return another function; for example, `-{a+1}` is the same as `{-(a+1)}`. So the above is equivalent to

```
{MN(_NaM"lcowbe")//^2}
```

which works as follows:

```
{                    }  Function, in which a is the 1st argument (the string)
    _Na                 Lambda fn: returns number of times its argument occurs in a
       M"lcowbe"        Map that function to the characters of "lcowbe"
                   ^2   A devious way to get [2]: split the scalar 2 into characters
   (            )//     Int-divide the list of character counts by [2]
                        Since the lists are not the same length, this divides the first
                          element (# of l's) by 2 and leaves the others alone
 MN                     Take the min of the resulting list
```

Now that we have that, here's the full program:

```
T$<(MN{_NaM"lcowbe"}//^2M[aYa@<i])++iy
                                        a is 1st cmdline arg, i is 0 (implicit)
T                                       Loop till condition is true:
                            a@<i        Slice leftmost i characters of a
                           Y            Yank that into y variable
                         [a     ]       List containing a and that value
                        M               To that list, map...
    MN{_NaM"lcowbe"}//^2                ... the cowbell function
                                        Result: a list containing the amount of cowbell
                                        in the original string and the amount in the slice
 $<(                             )      Fold on less-than: true if the first element is
                                        less than the second, otherwise false
                                  ++i   In the loop, increment i
                                     y  Once the loop exits, print y (the latest slice)
```

Comment: I entered `cowbell cowbell cowbee` and the output was `cowbellcowbelcowbel` but I might be using the IDE wrong (new to PIP)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I get `cowbell cowbell cowbeecowbell` ([try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@x@iYqPh61cd75foq5STnF@elKpUq68fZ@QbnRiZ6GCTGauprZ1Z@f//f7BcTo4CCp0KAA)). Are you using TIO or a local copy?

Comment: Oh nice! I was sticking it under the field "input" not under the argument add. +1

Comment: Really top class. I ported it to javascript.

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>511</s> <s>488</s> <s>474</s> <s>470</s> <s>463</s> 454

```C
void f(char*a){char*s;int i=-1,c,o,w,b,e=b=w=o=c=1,l=3,n,r,z=i;for(;s=a[++i];c+=s==67,o+=s==79,w+=s==87,b+=s==66,e+=s==69,l+=s==76);r=~-l/2;n=c<o?c:o;n=w<n?w:n;n=b<n?b:n;n=e<n?e:n;n=r<n?r:n;c=c==n;o=o==n;w=w==n;b=b==n;e=e==n;if(l=r==n?l:0)if(l%2)l=2;else l=1,c=o=w=b=e=0;else l+=l%2;n=c+o+w+b+e+l;for(printf("%s",a);s=n?a[++z]:0;s==67&&c?n--,c--:0,s==79&&o?n--,o--:0,s==87&&w?n--,w--:0,s==66&&b?n--,b--:0,s==69&&e?n--,e--:0,s==76&&l?n--,l--:0,putchar(s));}
```

**[Try it online](https://ideone.com/nHlBNZ)**

---

Readable format + explanation:

```C
void f(char*a){
//a = input

    char*s;

    int i=-1,c,o,w,b,e=b=w=o=c=1,l=3,n,r,z=i;//c,o,w,b,e all start at 1; L starts at 3

    for(;s=a[++i];c+=s==67,o+=s==79,w+=s==87,b+=s==66,e+=s==69,l+=s==76);
    //loop to obtain number of times each character C,O,W,B,E,L is found in string (using the ASCII numeric values of each letter)

    //to get an extra cowbell we need to increment C,O,W,B,E by 1 and L by 2 (two Ls in cowbell); except we don't have to because we already did that by starting them at c=1, o=1, w=1, b=1, e=1, L=3 when we declared them. 

    r=~-l/2;
    //r is half of (1 less the number of times L is in string (+ init value))

    n=c<o?c:o;n=w<n?w:n;n=b<n?b:n;n=e<n?e:n;n=r<n?r:n;
    //n is the number of times that the least occouring character appears in the string, (use R instead of L since cowbell has two L's in it and we just need ~-l/2)

    c=c==n;o=o==n;w=w==n;b=b==n;e=e==n;
    //convert c,o,w,b,e to BOOL of whether or not we need 1 more of that letter to create one more cowbell (logic for L handled below since it's trickier)

    if(l=r==n?l:0)//if L-1/2 is [or is tied for] least occurring character do below logic, else set l to 0 and skip to `else`
        if(l%2)//if l is divisible by 2 then we need 2 more Ls
            l=2;
        else //otherwise we just need 1 more l and no other letters
            l=1,c=o=w=b=e=0;
    else //add 1 to L if it's divisible by 2 (meaning just 1 more L is needed in addition to possibly other C,O,W,B,E letters) (*Note: L count started at 3, so a count of 4 would be divisible by 2 and there is only 1 L in the string)
        l+=l%2;

    n=c+o+w+b+e+l;
    //n = number of specific characters we need before we reach 1 more cowbell

    for(printf("%s",a);s=n?a[++z]:0;s==67&&c?n--,c--:0,s==79&&o?n--,o--:0,s==87&&w?n--,w--:0,s==66&&b?n--,b--:0,s==69&&e?n--,e--:0,s==76&&l?n--,l--:0,putchar(s));
    //loop starts by printing the original string, then starts printing it again one character at a time until the required number of C,O,W,B,E,L letters are reached, then break (s=n?a[++z]:0) will return 0 when n is 0. Each letter subtracts from n only when it still requires letters of its type (e.g. b?n--,b--:0)

}
```

---

Some Fun Tricks Used:

•When checking characters I type `'w'` for the char w which is 3 bytes, but for the characters `'c'` and `'b'` I can type their ASCII values 99 and 98 respectively to save a byte each time. *(Edit: Thanks to @Titus I know do this with all COWBELL letters by using uppercase input only which are all 2 bytes numeric ascii values)*

•`r=~-l/2` is `r=(l-1)/2` using bitshifts

•`a[++i]` I'm getting the character at index(i) and iterating the index all at the same time. I just start `i` at `i=-1` instead of `i=0` (I do the same with `z` and start it as `z=i` to save another byte)

Comment: Save 8 bytes with uppercase input: all ASCII codes below 100.

Comment: @Titus Brilliant! Thank you Titus, editing now

Comment: We currently have a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945901/is-the-second-int-in-a-multiple-declaration-always-set-to-1#41946031) regarding your statement "The second defined int (in this case `c`) is always set as 1 [...]." We'd be glad to have your statement as to why you think so over there because it just seems odd to some of us.

Comment: @Albert could it be that your program just relies on `c,o,w,b,e` to be initialized to the same value, instead of 1? Because your hint #2 seems to be not true, not for the C I know at least. Can you clarify? [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41945901/481061)

Comment: @FelixDombek I wish you had just asked here first before posting on SO; the amount of downvotes flying in from that site has completely killed my post. It's simply a matter of a typo in my code, I meant to say e=b=w=o=c=1. The second defined int (c) is always set as 1 this way so I can shorten it to just e=b=w=o=c=1. Editing my code now

Comment: @FelixDombek Now that I've fixed it, it seems it's not actually any shorter that way so oh well haha

Comment: Hm, I didn't think about that. Given that your code was already looked upon, and improved, by others, I was puzzled but also willing to accept that C works the way you say in the hint, which is easy to misunderstand. But I don't think your post deserved a downvote. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @FelixDombek thanks for pointing it out too! It is def. undefined behavior, I just simulated it (looped) on many IDEs and it seems to always init the int as 0. I probably could leave it after all, though my logic was designed to have them all set at 1; the fact that the test cases are working with it at 0 is coincidence I think. Cheers

Comment: Why `char*s`? Shouldn't it be `char s`?

Comment: @axiac C isn't my native language so I don't know much about how variables are declared, that may very well work but it's the same bytes either way

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, <s>125</s> <s>113</s> 112 bytes

```
n=lambda s:min(s.count(c)>>(c=='l')for c in "cowbel")
def f(s,i=0):
 while n(s)==n(s+s[:i]):i+=1
 return s+s[:i]
```

---

`n` counts the number of cowbells

---

-12 bytes thanks to @Rod
-1 byte thanks to @Titus

Comment: you dont need `[]` for the list comprehension when it's the only parameter, also you can drop `enumerate` :`min(s.count(c)/-~(c=='l')for c in"cowbel")` where `-~(n=='l')` is a shorter way to write `1+(n=='l')`

Comment: Wouldn´t `>>` be shorter than `/-~`?

Comment: @Titus you're right

Comment: There was an attempted edit that would have removed a byte by replacing the last newline space with a single semicolon.

Comment: @Möbius Wouldn't the `return` be in the while-loop then?

Comment: @ovs I don't really know I am a little fuzzy on this area of python.  I just thought you might want to know that there was an attempted edit on your question.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 91 bytes

```perl6
{my &c={.comb.Bag.&{|.<c o w b e>,.<l>div 2}.min}
first *.&c>.&c,($_ X~[\,](.comb)».join)}
```

Assumes lower-case input.

#### How it works

Inside the lambda, another lambda for counting the number of cowbells in a string is defined as such:

```perl6
my &c={                                        }  # Lambda, assigned to a variable.
       .comb                                      # Split the string into characters.
            .Bag                                  # Create a Bag (maps items to counts).
                .&{                       }       # Transform it into:
                   |.<c o w b e>,                 #   The counts of those letters, and
                                 .<l>div 2        #   half the count of "l" rounded down.
                                           .min   # Take the minimum count.
```

The rest of the code uses this inner lambda `&c` to find the result, like this:

```perl6
                     [\,](.comb)».join   # All prefixes of the input,
               ($_ X~                 )  # each appended to the input.
first         ,                          # Return the first one for which:
      *.&c>                              #   The cowbell count is greater than
           .&c                           #   the cowbell count of the input.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

*1 byte off thanks to @DLosc's idea of using the template string `lcowbe` instead of `cowbel`*

```
n`Gt@q:)hXK!'lcowbe'=s32BQ/kX<wy-Q]xK
```

Input characters are all lowercase. If the input contains newlines, the newline character needs to be entered as its ASCII code concatenated with the normal characters (see last input in the link with all test cases).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5@X4F7iUGilmRHhraiek5xfnpSqbltsbOQUqJ8dYVNeqRsYW@H9/796UqpCeWpOjo5CQVF@elFibm5mXrpCQWlVVU5qsYKaQnJ@SqpCen5OmjoA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#fZBbTwIxEIXf/RXDi40Ji7c3o4kxPsETiQ8khoS2O@xWell6ocCfxymiKFEnTbbTc75p98wmw52dDePj8u6inYx6TEuXBbKHcHvzNL5cTO7zphpP16Pd88uOydarEF3XoofM9QItCGwCzJ0H4zzCHta6x85YbBGWSckFCO@yJc8a3pLpArgV4UXWfLuB2jXkPoDHHZx8/1RIEBK1y7ThQtY4b1r1ttDGum7pQ0yrvN5sCy4JoBICS@lSBUbI1PSh867x3BhlG@jSdqsxwDldUiM0Ts/JqukXDaguJEPPpg6CisANxj75bEAZMSYPvFadCrIMQq1IDFgTAKhSMK6GiKYjWFmpalUnGyFFCkOUBDF@jEYwvLEcuFbLxAeQXaZUX5msZCUqyeD6qiymoOUrBF7S6MNXVwIa7E0stb19W8ky4j/oEOw37nByRIvwedL/Lv@Eqk/lRP5N2g@evgM).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 106 <s>107 113 126 141</s>

A porting to javascript of the Pip answer by @DLosc. I needed some time to fully understand it, and it's genius.

**Edit** -15 bytes following the hint by @Titus, directly appending chars to the input string `a` and avoiding early return (so no `for/if`)

**Edit 2** enumerating the 6 value for the Min function saves other 13 bytes

**Edit 3** changed c function again. I thought the verbose `length` and `split` would be too lengthy. I was wrong.

Assuming lowercase input

```js
a=>[...a].some(z=>c(a+=z)>b,c=a=>Math.min(...[...'lcowbe'].map((c,i)=>~-a.split(c).length>>!i)),b=c(a))&&a
```

*Less golfed*

```js
a=>{
  c=a=>{ // cowbell functions - count cowbells
    k = [... 'lcowbe'].map((c,i) => 
          (a.split(c).length - 1) // count occurrences of c in a
           / (!i + 1) // divide by 2 if first in list ('l')
    );
    return Math.min(...k);
  };
  b = c(a); // starting number of cowbells
  [...a].some(z => ( // iterate for all chars of a until true
    a += z,
    c(a) > b // exit when I have more cowbells
  ));
  return a;
}
```

**Test**

```js
f=
a=>[...a].some(z=>c(a+=z)>b,c=a=>Math.min(...[...'lcowbe'].map((c,i)=>~-a.split(c).length>>!i)),b=c(a))&&a

;["christopher walken begs for more cowbell!"
,"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
,"cowbell"
,"cowbell cowbell cowbell"
,"cowbell cowbell cowbel"
,"bcelow"
,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
,"cccowwwwbbeeeeelllll"
,"be well, programming puzzles & code golf"
,"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. wow!"
,`c-c-b-c
 
i have a cow, i have a bell.
uh! bell-cow!
i have a cow, i have a cowbell.
uh! cowbell-cow!
 
bell-cow, cowbell-cow.
uh! cow-cowbell-bell-cow.
cow-cowbell-bell-cow!
`].forEach(x=>console.log(x+'\n\n'+f(x)))
```

Comment: I guess that `k[x]++` would fail due to `undefined`. But I am pretty certain that `for(i=0;c(a)==c(a+=a[i++]);),a` works.

Comment: @Titus I'm not sure to understand. I'll give it a try

Comment: @Titus wow 15 bytes saved, thanks alot

Comment: `>>!i` saves 3 bytes. Why don´t you use `c(a+=z)`?

Comment: @Titus I use `c(a+=z)`. Not in the *less golfed* version, as it is, you see, less golfed. Using `>>!i` saves 1 byte (in the golfed version). Thanks again

Comment: IC. Are You sure that You need `b=c(a)` in the golfed version? `c(a)<c(a+=z)` should work, saving 3 bytes: `c(a)` will be evaluated before `a+=z`.

Comment: @Titus each time you suggest me something, it seems obviously wrong at first. Then I think again about it and, duh, you're right. I wanted to keep the original number of cowbells, before repeatedly modifying the string inside the loop. But all in all, do I need it? Probably not

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 184 bytes

```bash
f()(tr -cd cowbel<<<"$1"|sed 's/\(.\)/\1\
/g'|sort|uniq -c|awk '{print int($1/(($2=="l")?2:1))}'|sort -n|head -1)
for((m=1;`f "$1${1:0:m}"`!=$[`f "$1"`+1];m++)){ :;}
echo "$1${1:0:$m}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#dY/JjoMwEETv/orGsoQtcBhzZNF8SBgJYkxAYcmwJAfMtzOeIcsckkNL1dWv1Kq1oIyOPXCZg@yuB1VHUYSJwHpQOdiDl9BdwrxEJMg72nro@lFPbfVtAjq7nsCez33VjmCGEuFRSvw4xjVmn34gGFu2CPBWlyrLgQuGiq6ntIlFmBZgPpFZBB9Bs@DUisl@83DqiK@wcRzGZgjCBSlZdk@YGHpdV8klP3CJUAVldlGQ/TZw4bGZMvUOTaX1p7g5Wu/QrfqNvi1bAN2l@99/gPxuPi@vXAv9AA)

Thanks to @AlbertRenshaw for golfing 2 bytes off.

Comment: This can be golfed further for example just removing the spaces before and after the `!=`

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Thank you -- I thought I had tried that and gotten a syntax error, but you're right. The awk part may be golfable more too; I'm not very familiar with awk.

Comment: Yeah I naively tried removing other spaces and linebreaks in your code and was getting syntax errors but on that one it worked ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>80</s> <s>87</s> 97 bytes

```matlab
s=input('');k=1;do;until(x=@(A)min(fix(sum('cowbel'==A')./('111112'-48))))(b=[s s(1:++k)])>x(s);b
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#yA7tv)

Comment: This doesn't work when we need two `l`s to complete the additional cowbell. For example, on input `cowbell`, it incorrectly returns `cowbellcowbel` rather than `cowbellcowbell`. (I hope you can fix it—I like the atypical algorithm!)

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! I will chek it!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>124</s> 114 bytes

*Thanks to Neil for saving a few bytes*

```
a=>eval("for(c=0,d=a;(A=$=>Math.min([...'cowbel'].map(_=>($.split(_).length-1)>>(_=='l'))))(a)==A(d+=a[c++]););d")
```

Since this is quite different from the already existing JavaScript answer, and I put quite some time into this, I decided to create an answer myself.

### Usage

```
f=a=>eval("for(c=0,d=a;(A=$=>Math.min([...'cowbel'].map(_=>($.split(_).length-1)>>(_=='l'))))(a)==A(d+=a[c++]););d")
f("cowbell")
```

#### Output

```
"cowbellcowbell"
```

Comment: `.sort()[0]` is a marvellous idea. `eval` is evil. :D

Comment: Thanks ;-) I first used `Math.min()`, but that cost a lot of characters, and I figured there'd be a shorter way. And yes, `eval` is really nice for golfing.

Comment: If only `.sort()[0]` worked, it would only cost 10 bytes, but it doesn't, and `.sort((a,b)=>a-b)[0]` costs 20 bytes but `Math.min(...)` only costs 13.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 37

```
q___S\+{+"cowbel"1$fe=)2/+:e<\}%()#)<
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q___S%5C%2B%7B%2B%22cowbel%221%24fe%3D)2%2F%2B%3Ae%3C%5C%7D%25()%23)%3C&input=cowbell%2C%20needs%20moar%20)

If I can exclude the `"` and `\` characters, then…

### 35 bytes

```
q___`{+"cowbel"1$fe=)2/+:e<\}%()#)<
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q___%60%7B%2B%22cowbel%221%24fe%3D)2%2F%2B%3Ae%3C%5C%7D%25()%23)%3C&input=cowbell%2C%20needs%20moar%20)

**Explanation**

The code successively appends each character of the string to the initial string (going from original to doubled), determines the number of cowbells for each string (counting the number of occurrences of each character in "cowbel" and dividing the one for 'l' by 2, then taking the minimum), finds the position of the first string where the number of cowbells increases by 1, then takes the corresponding prefix of the input and puts it after the input string.

In order to include the original string too (with no character appended), the code prepends a neutral character to the string that's being iterated. The first version prepends a space, and the 2nd version uses the string representation, i.e. the string between double quotes.

```
q___          read input and make 3 more copies: one for output, one for prefix,
               one for appending and one for iterating
S\+           prepend a space to the iterating string
              or
`             get the string representation
{…}%          map each character of the string
  +           append the character to the previous string
  "cowbel"    push this string
  1$          copy the appended string
  fe=         get the number of occurrences of each "cowbel" character
  )2/+        take out the last number, divide by 2 and put it back
  :e<         find the minimum
  \           swap with the appended string
(             take out the first number (cowbells in the initial string)
)#            increment and find the index of this value in the array
)             increment the index (compensating for taking out one element before)
<             get the corresponding prefix
              another copy of the input is still on the stack
              and they are both printed at the end
```

Comment: I'm fine with you excluding the " and \ characters!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 133 bytes

a PHP port of @edc65´s JavaScript port of DLosc´s Pip answer.

```php
function f($s){for(;$c=lcowbe[$i];)$a[$c]=substr_count($s,$c)>>!$i++;return min($a);}for($s=$argv[1];f($s)==f($s.=$s[$i++]););echo$s;
```

takes lower case input from command line argument. Run with `-nr`.

**breakdown**

```php
// function to count the cowbells:
function f($s)
{
    for(;$c=lcowbe[$i];)            # loop through "cowbel" characters
        $a[$c]=substr_count($s,$c)  # count occurences in $s
            >>!$i++;                # divide by 2 if character is "l" (first position)
        return min($a);             # return minimum value
}
for($s=$argv[1];    # copy input to $s, loop:
    f($s)               # 1. count cowbells in $s
    ==                  # 3. keep looping while cowbell counts are equal
    f($s.=$s[$i++])     # 2. append $i-th character of $s to $s, count cowbells
;);
echo$s;             # print $s
```